# how can i access my env file from a nestjs module using passport js?

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

I am working on a small api using nestjs and passeport js

I have been trying to access the content of my env file, from within my auth module...but it's surpinsigly challenging...

```js
import { userService } from 'src/user/services/user.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  providers: [AuthService, userService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity, SpotEntity, SpotUserEntity]),
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: ConfigService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '600s' },
    }),
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Off course this cannot work because i am trying to utilize `ConfigService.get()` instead of `this.configService.get()`
I know i would need to instanciate `configService` in a constructor first, but modules do not have constructors, this is where i'm stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try registerAsync i.e

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


......
 imports: [
    PassportModule.register({
      defaultStrategy: 'jwt',
    }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: config.get<string>('JWT_EXPIRY'),
          },
          secret: config.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
  ]
....
```